# basename command is outputting an 'enter' character along with the file name

Tags: linux, command-line, bash, unix, shell

I'am reading a text file line by line using while loop whose contents are directories and file names. I read the file names using basename command. I want to check if that file exists in a directory. But the below written code does'nt work. When i echo the basename command, it is outputting an 'enter' character along with the file name. How do i remove the 'enter character' ?

```
while read line;do
   file=`basename "$line"`
   dir=`dirname "$line"`
   if [ -f "/data/config/${file}" ]; then
    echo "${file} is present"
   fi
done < /data/textfile.txt*
```

**content of textfile.txt is given below**

```
config/local/common/environment.properties
config/local/common/jmsservices.xml
config/local/common/ejbservices.xml
```

Comment: `echo -n` - Do not output the trailing newline.

Comment: Please take a look at [editing-help](http://superuser.com/editing-help).

Answer (score 1):

Per `man basename`:

```
NAME
   basename - strip directory and suffix from filenames 
...
   -z, --zero
          end each output line with NUL, not newline
```

If you decide to use `-z`, the shell might complain about the NUL, meaning you might have to [send the error stream to `/dev/null`](https://askubuntu.com/questions/350208/what-does-2-dev-null-mean).

Comment: -z is a GNU specific option.

Answer (score 0):

This is the default behaviour of `echo`. From the man page

> The echo utility writes any specified operands, separated by single blank (`') characters and followed by a newline (`\n') character, to the standard output.

You can specify `-n` to avoid the addition of the newline:

> ```
>  -n    Do not print the trailing newline character.  This may also be achieved by appending `\c' to the end of the string, as is done by iBCS2 compatible systems.  Note that this option
>        as well as the effect of `\c' are implementation-defined in IEEE Std 1003.1-2001 (``POSIX.1'') as amended by Cor. 1-2002.  Applications aiming for maximum portability are
>        strongly encouraged to use printf(1) to suppress the newline character.
> ```

Answer (score 0):

you can remove the extra enter using `tr`
`basename "$PWD" | tr -d '\n'`